# IntStream.reduce() returns wrong result

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

*My code:*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(arraySign(new int[]{41,65,14,80,20,10,55,58,24,56,28,86,96,10,3,
                84,4,41,13,32,42,43,83,78,82,70,15,-41}));
    }

    public static int arraySign(int[] nums) {

        int product = Arrays.stream(nums).reduce(1, (acc, a) -> acc * a);

        if (product != 0)
            return product / Math.abs(product);

        return product;
    }
}
```

*Expected result:* `-1`.

Can you explain why the method above returns `0`?

Comment: Looks like your multiplication is overflowing at some point.

Comment: From the orders of magnitude alone I'd expect the result of the reduction to have 21 digits minimum. So it's definitely overflowing - integers have a maximum value of about 2 billion (so 10 digits at most) and longs have about 20 digits max so you'd need to use `BigInteger` for your calculation.

Comment: Hint: try logging each result as you produce it, in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as it has been mentioned in the comments, you're getting integer overflow. With multiplication, it happens very quickly.

We can make use of `BigInteger` to visualize the values:

```
BigInteger productBi = Arrays.stream(nums)
    .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
    .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, (acc, a) -> {
        System.out.println(acc);
        return acc.multiply(a);
    });
```

With your sample-data, the code would produce:

```
1
41
2665
37310
2984800
59696000
596960000
32832800000 // <- already larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE
...
```

It shows that overflow happens at the very beginning of the calculation. To find the point when the product becomes zero, let's switch to the initial code:

```
int product = Arrays.stream(nums).reduce(1, (acc, a) -> {
    System.out.println(acc + " * " + a);
    return acc * a;
});
```

Would produce:

```
1 * 41
41 * 65
2665 * 14
...
1342177280 * 32 // <- here product turs to zero
0 * 42
...
more zero
```

It's clear that multiplication of `1342177280` and `32` gives `0`. Let's take a look at these numbers in binary using `Integer.toBinaryString()`:

```
Bits: 1010000000000000000000000000000 // 1342177280
Bits: 100000                          // 32
```

According to the [§15.17.1. Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1) when overflow occurs, only low-order bits would be preserved. And in this case, all low-order bits are zero, therefore the product would not contain significant bits and the result would be `0`.

> If an integer **multiplication overflows**, then the **result is the low-order bits** of the mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format.